# Vector spaces with prime number of elements are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two vector spaces $V,W$, both having  exactly $p$ elements, for some prime $p$, is it true that $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic?

Comment: vector spaces over **which** field?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It is for **you** to deduce.

Comment: Get a basis. The number of elements is equal to the size of the basis raised to the size of the scalars. Therefore, the size of the scalars is $p$ and the size of the basis is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since the base field can only be $\mathbb{F}_p$ and both spaces will have dimension $1$ then.